# ASP.NET & Entity Framework : PDF report don’t render on local iis server

Tags: excel, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, pdf-generation, asp.net-4.5

I am working on an Entity Framework & ASP.NET web application. There are some reports where I select values and set dates then clicks to generate the PDF or Excel.

My issue is the PDF and Excel function renders properly when I run the application on Visual Studio. But when I publish the application and run from a local IIS server, the PDF and Excel files don't get rendered, instead it opens a new tab with the same page.

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Please add the "generate" code

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply. The problem has been resolve. Asp.net Published File didn't contained the RDLC folder where i locate all the .rdlc file which generates report. That's why the live server was unable to render the report. But my project file contained the RDLC folder that's why all my report was working on debug mode at visual studio. So i copy RDLC folder and paste that file to my rood directory where all my files located.